# Extract checkbook value from a closed spreadsheet using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly larger number of excel workbooks in a folder.  Each workbook has one tab - Sheet1.  Sheet1 includes three checkboxs: Checkbox 6, Checkbox 7 and Checkbox 8 in addition to some values in cells. I'm using this code:

[Link to Code Used](https://www.exceltip.com/files-workbook-and-worksheets-in-vba/read-information-from-a-closed-workbook-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html)

to extract the cell values, but was hoping it would also be possible to determine the value (status checked or not checked) of each of the checkboxes.  Is this possible?  Note - None of the checkbox are linked to a particular cell.

Comment: You'd need to open the workbook programmatically to get the checkbox value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to read anything from a *closed* file. Even the code you are linking to cannot do this. You will always need a program that *opens* the file, read the data from it, find the information you want and *close* it again.

For Excel files you usually use Excel, but it could be something else - I know that Python has an library to read & write Excel files (and there are more), but all of them have to *open* the file. *Open* means ask the operating system to read the data from disk, maybe set a lock, maybe later write it back, those kind of things.

That said, what you probably want is to access the data (in your case checkbox settings) without the sheet being visible. You can do so by set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, open the file, read the checkbox values, close the file and reset `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. The user will not see anything. I strongly assume that the Excel4-Macro does the same, but you will not find many persons around that are able to deal with Excel4-Macros.

Now to be able to read the value of a checkbox, you need to know if you are dealing with *ActiveX* or *Form* controls (or both). I wrote a small prove of concept that can deal with both. You pass the name of a workbook, the name (or number) of a sheet and an array with the name of the checkboxes you want to read. Result is an array with the values of the checkboxes. However you need to know that the values of an ActiveX-checkbox is `True` or `False` (or `Null` if you allow TripleState), while for a form-checkbox it is `xlOn` or  `xlOff`. In the case a sheet doesn't have a checkbox with the specific name, it will return an arbitrary number

```
Function getCheckBoxValueFromFile(filename As String, sheet As Variant, checkboxNames) As Variant
    Const undefinded = -999

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)
    
    Dim i As Integer, res()
    ReDim res(LBound(checkboxNames) To UBound(checkboxNames))
    
    For i = LBound(checkboxNames) To UBound(checkboxNames)
        Dim val As Long
        val = undefinded
        With wb.Sheets(sheet)
            On Error Resume Next
            ' first try ActiveX-CheckBox
            val = .OLEObjects(checkboxNames(i)).Object.Value
            ' if failed, try Form-CheckBox
            If val = undefinded Then val = .CheckBoxes(checkboxNames(i)).Value
            On Error GoTo 0
            res(i) = val
        End With
    Next i
    wb.Close False
    getCheckBoxValueFromFile = res
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

To test the function:

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim res, i, cbNames
    cbNames = Array("CheckBox1", "Check Box 2")
    res = getCheckBoxValueFromFile("C:\TEMP\Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1", cbNames)
    For i = LBound(res) To UBound(res)
        Debug.Print i & ": " & cbNames(i) & " -> " & res(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```